# Javascript: inverting a boolean does not work

Tags: javascript, boolean

i am trying to invert a boolean value (toggle);

```
var current_state=$.cookie('state');
if(current_state==null) {
  current_state=false;
}
console.log(current_state);
current_state=(!current_state);
console.log(current_state);

$.cookie('state', current_state, { expires: 7, path: '/' });
```

In my opinion the second `console.log` should display the opposite of the first one, but both calls report `false`. Whats up here?

Comment: why are you re-declaring the "current_state" ??

Comment: What if you tried this? `var current_state = $.cookie('state') == "false"?false:true;`

Comment: FYI you dont have to do `($.cookie('state') == "false")?false:true;` because the condition evaluates to true or false, so just do this: `var current_state = ($.cookie('state') != "false");`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `$.cookie('state')` seems to be a string ("`false`").

As a proof, see the following code (also in [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7ptwE/)):

```
var current_state='false';
if(current_state==null) {
  current_state=false;
}
console.log(current_state);
var current_state=(!current_state);
console.log(current_state);
```

It outputs `false` twice.

Why? Because you check if it is null and do not support other cases.

You can do something like this:

```
var current_state='false';
if(current_state==null ||
    current_state==false ||
    current_state=='false') {
    current_state = false;
}else{
    current_state = true;
}
console.log(current_state);
current_state=(!current_state);
console.log(current_state);
```

and your code will output boolean `true` or `false` first and then the opposite boolean value.

Comment: Thank you, changed the first line to `var current_state=$.cookie('webcam_auto_cycle')=='1';` and it works as expected now. Seems like if i write a boolean via the JQuery cookie plugin it gets converted into a String.

Comment: @rohk: You are totally incorrect - it depends on the string. For example `!!'false'` will give you `true` (see [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/msBHk/)). Converting with `!!` works on integers (not strings!).

Comment: @Tadeck: Theoretically it works with any data type, but `"false"` is a non-empty string, therefore, it's boolean equivalent is `true`...

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure that in the case that `current_state` is not `null` that it is actually a boolean value? Perhaps it's a string?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that current_state is not a boolean but a string

```
var current_state=$.cookie('state');
if(current_state==null) {
    current_state=false;
}   

console.log(current_state);
var current_state= current_state == 'false' ? "true" : "false"; // (!current_state);
console.log(current_state);
$.cookie('state', current_state);
```